# Disable auto rendering in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I need is to disable the automatic page (HTML) rendering in rails and override it with a after_action method. What I'm trying to achieve is an equivalent of CakePHP $this->autoRender = false;

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  after_action :custom_render

  layout nil # Tried this but didn't worked

  def custom_render
      render #[...]
  end


end
```

some_controller.rb

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

    def index
        # No rendering here
    end

end
```

As shown in the code I tried to add a layout nil to prevent all actions from rendering, but that doesn't seem to affect the behaviour of the action.

Comment: That's not really what `after_action` is for. The whole point is that it has access to the rendered response. If you want to write a custom render method, there are [better ways](http://beerlington.com/blog/2011/07/25/building-a-csv-renderer-in-rails-3/). If you can tell us more about your actual problem we can probably offer a better solution than an equivalent to `$this->autoRender = false`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm trying to create a theme switcher, the ApplicationController selects from the database the theme chosen by the user, and renders the appropriate template.

Comment: Seems like you want to route to a `ThemesController`'s `random` action then...? What is there to do inside your action, if ApplicationController does all the rendering?

Comment: Why can't you use a before_action to select your theme?

Comment: I came up with the solution of overriding the render method inside the ApplicationController to render a specific file

Answer (score 2):

Haven't checked whether it works with Rails 4, but this patch works for Rails 5.

According to the code of [BasicImplicitRender](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b5db73076914e7103466bd76bec785cbcfe88875/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb) and [ImplicitRender](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5033e2c08232a5e6e740fb6c117daeb51d5ef2c1/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb#L33), `send_action` of is `BasicImplicitRender` responsible for calling `default_render`

Documentation says:

> For API controllers, the implicit response is always 204 No Content.
>
> For all other controllers, we use ... heuristics to decide whether to
>   render a template, raise an error for a missing template, or respond with
>   204 No Content ...

So I suppose redefining `default_render` method will serve you purpose.

In your controller:

```
def a
  # uses `default_render` unless you call `render` method explicitly
end

def b
  render plain: 'Custom text for b' # `default_render` won't be called
end

private

# This does the trick
#
def default_render
  render plain: 'Text'
end
```

You may also hack `send_action` just like [it is done in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b5db73076914e7103466bd76bec785cbcfe88875/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb#L6) so as to even skip `default_render` call at all:

```
module ActionController
  module BasicImplicitRender # :nodoc:
    def send_action(method, *args)
      # super.tap { default_render unless performed? }
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable rendering (well return nothing) issue.

```
def index
  render :nothing
end
```

But it's too late to do anything, as it will return response with empty body.

To disable layout:

```
def index
  render layout: false
end
```

This will render you view without a layout, issue (`render layout: 'my_custom_layout'`) to render default view but with different layout.

We don't know what you want, but the simplest solution is just to render a specific view, f.i.:

```
def index
  render 'my_custom_file.'
end
```

There are really many options: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

**EDIT** - as requested in a comment

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_user_template

  # ...

  def set_user_template
    template_name = current_user.template_name
    self.class.layout "#{template_name}/application"
  end
end
```